# On Android, why does the ps command show high virtual memory when an app hasn't allocated anything?

Tags: android

I'm using the ps command on Android to determine the memory being used by an application (just a normal Java-based app).  I have a test app that allocates as much memory as possible (by repeatedly creating 1 megabyte byte arrays an adding them to a List so they don't go out of reference, until an allocation fails).

The "RSS" (Resident Set Size) column shown by ps for the test app seems sensible - when the app starts up it is low, then after I have allocated a bunch of memory it is much higher.  But the VSIZE/VSS column is very high to begin with and doesn't change.  What is the meaning of the VSIZE/VSS column as reported by ps on Android?

Here is the output of ps for my test app before I explicitly allocate any memory.  The units are kilobytes

```
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
u0_a55    2271  91    468664 30008 ffffffff 00000000 S com.dave.quicktest
```

And here it is after I allocate memory until exhaustion:

```
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
u0_a55    2271  91    468692 287232 ffffffff 00000000 S com.dave.quicktest
```

RSS when up from 30mb to 287mb, a difference which roughly matches the amount of memory allocated.  But VSIZE was 468mb to begin with, and doesn't change much.  Why?

Also, can I confirm that the Android OS does not in practice use a pagefile/swap space?  I don't doubt it is possible to build/configure it to do so, but in normal, stock OS builds, does it ever do VM paging to storage?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android apps do not start by the usual fork() and exec() means with a clean process image.

Instead, an already running program called zygote is instructed to fork off a child and specialize it by changing to the application userid and loading the java (and potentially native) code libraries which form the particular application.

The reason for this odd behavior is that zygote has already "loaded" most of the system-provided java and native libraries which an Android application might want to use.  Since these contain mostly read-only code pages, a child process inherits access to them almost for free - there's no need to load a new copy into memory for each program.  And the few associated data pages which a running instance might need are only copied when actually written to.  So it's a very efficient scheme for minimizing duplicate memory use on resource constrained multiprocessing systems.

However, because all those libraries, needed or not, are mapped into each app's address space and theoretically available, the virtual memory size of each app will appear rather high.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  So are you saying that the RSS column shown by does _not_ include VM pages that are shared with other processes, but the VSIZE/VSS column _does_ include VM pages that are shared with other porcesses?